# Tricky Inhomogeneous Airy Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, airy-functions

just wondering if anyone can help out here.

I'm solving the following ODE:

$$\frac{\textrm{d}^{2}y_{2}}{\textrm{d}x^{2}}-xy_{2}
=\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}(xy_{1}),$$

where

$$y_{1}=\int\textrm{Ai}(x)\,\textrm{d}x.$$

The solution I have is

$$y_{2}=C_{1}\textrm{Ai}(x)+C_{2}\textrm{Bi}(x)-\pi\left[\textrm{Ai}(x)\int\textrm{Bi}(x)\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}(xy_{1})\,\textrm{d}x
-\textrm{Bi}(x)\int\textrm{Ai}(x)\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}(xy_{1})\,\textrm{d}x\right].$$

Using integration by parts gives

$$y_{2}=C_{1}\textrm{Ai}(x)+C_{2}\textrm{Bi}(x)+\pi\left[\textrm{Ai}(x)\int xy_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)\,\textrm{d}x
-\textrm{Bi}(x)\int xy_{1}\textrm{Ai}'(x)\,\textrm{d}x\right].$$

If I consider only the first of the 'tricky' integrals (if I can do one I can do both) I have that

$$\int xy_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)\,\textrm{d}x=\frac{x^{2}y_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)}{2}-\int\frac{x^{2}y_{1}'\textrm{Bi}'(x)}{2}\,\textrm{d}x-\int\frac{x^{2}y_{1}\textrm{Bi}''(x)}{2}\,\textrm{d}x.$$

Or, equivalently

$$\int xy_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)\,\textrm{d}x=\frac{x^{2}y_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)}{2}-\int\frac{x^{2}\textrm{Ai}(x)\textrm{Bi}'(x)}{2}\,\textrm{d}x-\int\frac{x^{2}y_{1}\textrm{Bi}''(x)}{2}\,\textrm{d}x.$$

The second term on the right-hand side has a closed form solution. Hence

$$\int xy_{1}\textrm{Bi}'(x)\,\textrm{d}x=\textrm{stuff that I know}-\int\frac{x^{2}y_{1}\textrm{Bi}''(x)}{2}\,\textrm{d}x.$$

I can't really see where else to go from here. I have tried parts on the remaining 'problem' term but that hasn't proved fruitful.

Am I simply going down a rabbit hole? Is a nice closed form solution even obtainable in this case?

Comment: I don't know if there is a closed form, but an integral solution is just as good as any other solution.